Trouble with combining 3d plots
I am having difficulties getting 3d plots to display correctly.  For reference, I am trying to plot regions with the surfaces being different colors to help students visualize the bounds on their triple integrals.  If I plot each of the following separately, they display just fine.  When I plot all of them, the bottom cone is only partially shown and the portion of the sphere shows only the top half and has weird patches removed.
cylinderPlot3D[f_, {rMin_, rMax_}, {tMin_, tMax_}, opts___] := 
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], f[r, t]}, {r, rMin, rMax}, {t, 
tMin, tMax}, opts]
f1[r_, t_] := r/Sqrt[3]; f2[r_, t_] := -r/Sqrt[3];
P1 = cylinderPlot3D[f1, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
PlotStyle -> Blue];
P2 = cylinderPlot3D[f2, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
PlotStyle -> Green]; 
P3 = ParametricPlot3D[{2*Sin[p]*Cos[t], 2*Sin[p]*Sin[t], 2*Cos[p]}, {p, 
Pi/3, 2*Pi/3}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, Mesh -> None];
Show[P1, P2, P3]




PlotRange->All
We can use RevolutionPlot3D to do the cylinder coordinate plot3d.

p12 = RevolutionPlot3D[
   f1[r, t], {r, -Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
   PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> Automatic, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
   MeshShading -> {Green, Lighter@Blue}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None];
p3 = RevolutionPlot3D[{2 Sin[p], 2 Cos[p]}, {p, π/3, 
    2 π/3}, {t, 0, 2 π}, MeshStyle -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> 80];
Show[p12, p3, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]



Calculate the volume

r = 2;
reg = ParametricRegion[{1 - s, s} . {{0, 0, 0}, 
    FromSphericalCoordinates[{r, θ, φ}]}, {{s, 0, 
    1}, {θ, π/3, (2 π)/3}, {φ, 0, 2 π}}]
reg//Region


(16 π)/3


You can use Opacity:
P1 = cylinderPlot3D[f1, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3, Blue]];
P2 = cylinderPlot3D[f2, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3, Green]];
P3 = ParametricPlot3D[{2*Sin[p]*Cos[t], 2*Sin[p]*Sin[t], 
    2*Cos[p]}, {p, Pi/3, 2*Pi/3}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3, Yellow]];

Show[P1, P2, P3
 , PlotRange -> All
 , Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}
 ]



